# When is the End Of Life for WildFly 26.1.2? Do we have this schedule for other WildFly releases as well?

Tags: wildfly

I'm trying to get the EOL for WildFly releases, so that we can move accordingly to the latest WildFly release. We don't want to upgrade to every new release WildFly does, but don't want to be on an EOL release.

I tried to get this information from the WildFly site, but I wasn't able to find this specific info.

Comment: Maybe switching to JBoss EAP is better for your purposes?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the answer of the WildFly users mailing list:

> We have no current plans for further releases in the 26.1.x series.
> Our general release policy is to do one bug fix release per feature
> version release. Any additional bug fix releases would be a policy
> exception, as 26.1.2 and 26.1.3 were. If something changes and we
> decide to do another 26.1.x release, I'd announce that decision on
> this forum. To be honest though, it seems like as time passes the odds
> of that happening go down.